# Windows 10: Switched from BIOS to UEFI. Hyper-V reports that the hypervisor is not running

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, uefi, hyper-v

I partitioned my hard drive and installed Debian on second partition. In order to do this I had to switch from BIOS to UEFI after basically destorying the MBR. Everything works great.  However when I choose to boot to Windows 10 my various images within Hyper-V are not starting.  The error states that hypervisor is not running.  Any ideas?

I tried this [Hyper-V reports that the hypervisor is not running. How to start the hypervisor?](https://superuser.com/questions/858259/hyper-v-reports-that-the-hypervisor-is-not-running-how-to-start-the-hypervisor) but no joy.  Any suggestions on why this would have stopped working?

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>Coreinfo.exe -v

Coreinfo v3.31 - Dump information on system CPU and memory topology
Copyright (C) 2008-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3340 CPU @ 3.10GHz
Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
Microcode signature: 00000020
HYPERVISOR      -       Hypervisor is present
VMX             *       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
EPT             *       Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT)
```

Comment: To be clear, you did completely reinstall Win10, yes? If so it may just be that the Hyper-V feature has not yet been enabled (it is not on by default). Also, please update the post with the verbiage from the _exact_ error message given.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hyper-V reports that the hypervisor is not running. How to start the hypervisor?](https://superuser.com/questions/858259/hyper-v-reports-that-the-hypervisor-is-not-running-how-to-start-the-hypervisor).  This duplicate was chosen due to the duplicate’s answer actually did solve the author’s problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out running command prompt as administrator and running `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto` followed by a reboot did actually work.  I stopped and started the service using the controls in Hyper-V Manager.  My VM was in a saved state. This reset itself.  My actions above followed by a second reboot seemed to do the trick.

One additional step was that I downloaded EasyBCD and checking through the options confirmed that Hyper-V support was enabled.

[Easy BCD screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEx0O.png)