# Login stuck on black screen with cursor after enabling Hyper-V hypervisor

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, black-screen-of-death, bcdedit

strange one. I enabled the Hyper-V feature on my works Win10 1803 Lenovo T450 (8GB RAM) laptop. Tried to create the first Windows Server VM but got the error:

> "...hyperpvisor is not running"

Googled and found this [useful page](https://superuser.com/questions/858259/hyper-v-reports-that-the-hypervisor-is-not-running-how-to-start-the-hypervisor/1160635), ran `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto` rebooted and everything all working, VMs loaded and running.

Upon next reboot of my laptop, it got stuck during the logon stage with a black screen but a cursor, I can still access task manager from ctrl+alt+del. noticed explorer.exe not in process list but trying to launch it from "run new task" did nothing. Eventually I realised if I rebooted with wifi turned off it will login all the way to the desktop but some strange things are happening

- Chrome wont open at all. chrome.exe quickly appears and disappears from process list.
- Cannot open elevated Powershell admin window, just opens and closes. non-elevated Powershell opens successfully
- Cannot open many control panel applets including hyper-v manager

If I revert `hypervisorlaunchtype` to off and reboot everything is okay, login normal with wifi on, three items above are fixed but my VM wont launch again "...hyperpvisor is not running" obviously because I've turned off the hypervisor.

Things I've tried:

- Disabled and re-enabled virtualisation in UEFI
- Turned off and on the Hyper-V feature
- Nothing obvious in event viewer
- ran a memory diag quick test in UEFI- PASSED

Below are `syteminfo` and `bcdedit` information

```
Host Name:                 *********
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
OS Version:                10.0.17134 N/A Build 17134
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Member Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          *********
Registered Organization:   *********
Product ID:                00329-00000-00003-AA665
Original Install Date:     25/04/2019, 10:06:20
System Boot Time:          31/05/2019, 13:16:00
System Manufacturer:       LENOVO
System Model:              20BUS4BV05
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 61 Stepping 4 GenuineIntel ~2295 Mhz
BIOS Version:              LENOVO JBET72WW (1.36 ), 23/02/2019
Windows Directory:         C:\WINDOWS
System Directory:          C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume2
System Locale:             en-gb;English (United Kingdom)
Input Locale:              en-gb;English (United Kingdom)
Time Zone:                 (UTC+00:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London
Total Physical Memory:     8,071 MB
Available Physical Memory: 4,587 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  9,351 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 5,280 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    4,071 MB
Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
Domain:                    *********
Logon Server:              \\*********
Hotfix(s):                 7 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                           [01]: KB4230204
                           [02]: KB4346084
                           [03]: KB4462930
                           [04]: KB4463318
                           [05]: KB4485449
                           [06]: KB4493478
                           [07]: KB4493464
Network Card(s):           3 NIC(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM
                                 Connection Name: Ethernet
                                 Status:          Media disconnected
                           [02]: Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265
                                 Connection Name: Wi-Fi
                                 DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                                 DHCP Server:     *********
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: *********
                                 [02]: *********
                           [03]: Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
                                 Connection Name: vEthernet (Default Switch)
                                 DHCP Enabled:    Yes
                                 DHCP Server:     *********
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: *********
                                 [02]: *********
Hyper-V Requirements:      VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
                           Second Level Address Translation: Yes
                           Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

bcdedit

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
badmemoryaccess         Yes
fverecoveryurl          https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=857635
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {1afc1e26-66d3-11e9-a3b7-ab5c344078f7}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {39fc9d94-6738-11e9-9c31-d90b3e4d3eec}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
badmemoryaccess         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {1afc1e26-66d3-11e9-a3b7-ab5c344078f7}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Off
hypervisorschedulertype Core
```

Comment: This might not be entirely related, but i had a similar sort of problem the other day. I couldn't open hardly any of the settings apps. They would open and instantly close. To fix that, we had to re-install the OS. To me, it sounds a bit like a file-corruption.